# Search not loading propely

Tags: windows-10

After update `explorer.exe` was "not working".

So I got older version by repair tool, and search does it's functionality, but it's not aesthetic, and I fell uncomfortable about this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> `explorer.exe` was "not working". So I got older version by repair tool

It takes more than just restoring an .exe file to get the old version back. Computer programs like this have many executable files, DLLs and associated resources. It is quite clear that the older version of `explorer.exe` is unable to access the resources in the newer DLL files. In this case, the resource is a CSS resource (probably hosted inside a DLL file).

Unfortunately, we can't point you to the resource file because Microsoft hasn't disclosed its location, and without their help, it is everyone's guess.

You have to try rolling back your computer to a time before the update.

Comment: I didnt used a exe, and just shift+restart there. And roleback not saving

Comment: You wrote "So I got older version by repair tool".

Comment: Repair tool, from windows

Comment: That's what I assumed too.

Comment: it solved itself '_', somehow every day was coming with little repairs to it, not it seems normal